# iCloud select multiple photos at the sametime

Tags: icloud, photos

In iCloud.com, I am unable to select multiple files at the sametime. I have tried CTRL and Shift keys that you normally would in apps.

Is multiple select really disabled in iCloud ?

Thanks and appreciate this community's help.

Sunil

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple files you would need to use Alt key.